# How can I overcome silent failure to change the PATH environment variable in VC++ 2013?

Tags: c++, windows, environment-variables

My goal is to write code that prepends a directory to the existing value of the PATH environment variable and sets the PATH environment variable to the new value for the duration of the program so that DLLs can be loaded from the new directory as well as from directories previously on the path. The code only needs to run on Windows and only needs to be compiled with Visual C++ 2013 and 2015. (Ideally, I'd like to be able to compile with MinGW as well, but the fact that there's no equivalent to /DELAYLOAD means that that may not be possible.)

I found, after experimentation, that SetEnvironmentVariable[W] silently fails to change the value of PATH, but _putenv, _putenv_s, _wputenv, and _wputenv_s work correctly --- but only on VC++ 2015. On VC++ 2013, they fail silently, and leave the value of PATH unchanged (the same way that SetEnvironmentVariable fails silently on VC++ 2013). I have not found any references to this behavior anywhere that I have searched on the Internet.

I can put up with using _putenv rather than SetEnvironmentVariable, but I need to figure out a way to change the value of PATH dynamically in VS2013, even if it's different from the way that works in VS2015.

UPDATE:

Here's `prependDirToEnvVarW()` (and `getPathFromEnvVarW()`, which it calls). `prependDirToEnvVarW()` works correctly on VC++ 2015 but silently fails to change the path on VC++ 2013.

```
inline std::wstring getPathFromEnvVarW()
{
    DWORD bufferSize = GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"PATH", NULL, 0);
    std::wstring ret(bufferSize, wchar_t(0));
    DWORD getPathEnv = GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"PATH", &ret[0], bufferSize);
    return (getPathEnv ? ret : L"");
}

inline bool prependDirToEnvVarW(const std::wstring & wstrDir)
{
    const std::wstring PATH_VAR_NAME = L"PATH";
    std::wstring wstrPrevPath = getPathFromEnvVarW();
    std::wstring wstrValue = wstrDir;
    if (!wstrValue.empty() && wstrValue[wstrValue.length() - 1] != L';')
    {
        wstrValue += L";";
    }
    wstrValue += wstrPrevPath;

    std::replace(wstrValue.begin(), wstrValue.end(), L'/', L'\\');

    errno_t retVal = _wputenv_s(PATH_VAR_NAME.c_str(), wstrValue.c_str());
    std::cout << "Attempted to change PATH to:\n" << 
        std::string(wstrValue.cbegin(), wstrValue.cend()) << std::endl;
    if (retVal == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "retVal is nonzero: " << retVal 
            << " (compare to EINVAL == " << EINVAL << ")" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: SetEnvironmentVariable should work if anything does.  You might need to post a [mcve].  On the other hand, DLLs should typically be loaded using an explicit path, which would avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: Note that it is (or used to be, IIRC) normal for `_putenv` to only affect the C environment, not the Windows environment.  So the code as currently posted can be expected to fail.  But it isn't clear to me what *exactly* you are doing with the PATH that makes you conclude that it isn't being changed; can you post that part of the code too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The premise is incorrect. The `PATH` is the *last* thing searched for DLLs.

Instead, you should be calling [SetDllDirectory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203.aspx) or [AddDllDirectory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513.aspx) . This sets the DLL search path so that your added path is searched *second*, right after the executable directory.

If you need finer control than that, you will need to specify a full pathname to the `LoadLibrary()` function.

Comment: Hey Remy, I don’t mind the edit, but you changed the links to absolute links to MS sites, which are notorious for moving stuff around. Did I err in having a make-google-find-it link to begin with?

Comment: If you're using the fully-qualified path, `LoadLibraryEx` with the `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` flag is a way to load dependencies from the target DLL's directory without having to modify `PATH` or call `SetDllDirectory`. If it's Windows 8+ or an updated Windows 7 system, you can also use the newer flags that give more control such as `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR`, set default flags via `SetDefaultDllDirectories`, and add directories using the more flexible `AddDllDirectory` function.

Comment: @Dúthomhas, AddDllDirectory() did not work for me, but LoadLibrary(_pathname_) did. Thanks!